# How to compare the cell values of two data tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datatable, compare

If i have two data tables with same structure,the same primary key and the same number of columns .

How to compare their `content` and detect the cells which are not the same in the two data tables ?

ex:

**TB_Offline**

```
emp_num(key)  salary      ov    

 455           3000      67.891   
 677           5000      89.112    
 778           6000      12.672
```

**TB_Online**

```
emp_num(key)  salary      ov  

 455           3000      67.891 
 677           5000      50.113 
 778           5500      12.672
```

---

I want to get result like this(or some structure to show the differences) :

```
emp_num(key)| salary_off |salary_on|s1   | ov_off  |  ov_on  |s2         

   677      |   5000     |    5000 | 1   |  89.112 |  50.113 | 0    
   778      |   6000     |    5500 | 0   |  12.672 |  12.672 | 1
```

---

**NOTE:**

> ```
> 455 doesn't exist in the result because it was the exact in all columns among the two datatables.
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According you the new requirements you might try this.

It first gets the primary key name - the `Unique` column, then the other columns names, creates a new `DataTable` with new column names, fills the values and creates an expression to compare the them:

```
void Main()
{
    // create some test data

    var dt1 = new DataTable();
    dt1.Columns.Add("emp_num", typeof(int));
    dt1.Columns.Add("salary", typeof(int));
    dt1.Columns.Add("ov", typeof(double));
    dt1.Columns[0].Unique = true;

    dt1.Rows.Add(455, 3000, 67.891);
    dt1.Rows.Add(677, 5000, 89.112);
    dt1.Rows.Add(778, 6000, 12.672);

    var dt2 = new DataTable();
    dt2.Columns.Add("emp_num", typeof(int));
    dt2.Columns.Add("salary", typeof(int));
    dt2.Columns.Add("ov", typeof(double));
    dt2.Columns[0].Unique = true;

    dt2.Rows.Add(455, 3000, 67.891);
    dt2.Rows.Add(677, 5000, 50.113);
    dt2.Rows.Add(778, 5500, 12.672);
    dt2.Rows.Add(779, 5500, 12.672);

    var result = CompareDataTables(dt1, dt2);
    result.Dump("Result");

}
```

`CompareDataTables` method:

```
static DataTable CompareDataTables(DataTable dt1, DataTable dt2)
{
    var keyName = dt1.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Single (x => x.Unique).ColumnName;
    var dt1Cols = dt1.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Where (x => !x.Unique).Select (x =>x.ColumnName );
    var dt2Cols = dt1.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Where (x => !x.Unique).Select (x =>x.ColumnName );

    // get keys from both data tables
    var keys = new HashSet<int>(dt1.AsEnumerable().Select (x => (int)x[keyName]));
    keys.UnionWith(dt2.AsEnumerable().Select (x => (int)x[keyName]));

    keys.Dump("keys");

    // create a new data table that will hold the results
    var result = new DataTable();
    result.Columns.Add(keyName, typeof(int));
    result.Columns[0].Unique = true;

    // initialize data and comparison columns
    foreach (var name in dt1Cols)
    {
        result.Columns.Add(name + "_off", dt1.Columns[name].DataType);
        result.Columns.Add(name + "_on", dt1.Columns[name].DataType);
        result.Columns.Add(name + "_same", typeof(bool), name + "_off = " + name + "_on");
    } 


    foreach (var key in keys)
    {
        // get a row from each data table with the current key
        var rowOff = dt1.Select(keyName + " = " + key).FirstOrDefault();
        var rowOn = dt2.Select(keyName + " = " + key).FirstOrDefault();

        // create a new row            
        var newRow = result.NewRow();

        // fill the new row with off data
        if (rowOff != null)
        {
            newRow[keyName] = rowOff[keyName];
            foreach (var name in dt1Cols)
            {
                newRow[name + "_off"] = rowOff[name];
            }
        }

        // fill the new row with on data
        if (rowOn != null)
        {
            foreach (var name in dt1Cols)
            {
                newRow[name + "_on"] = rowOn[name];
            }
            newRow[keyName] = rowOn[keyName];
        }

        // add the row to the result data table
        result.Rows.Add(newRow);        
    }

    return result;
}
```

[image: Summary2]

It's not bullet proof. It'd be a good idea to check if the data tables have the same structure.

Comment: Could U clarify what's `Dump` method ?
Is this a `.net` method ?

Comment: Oh, sorry. It's copy paste from `LINQPad` and `Dump` is its method to dump objects. It created the grids on the picture for easier debugging.

Answer (score 7):

Here's an implementation in a fairly generic method that compares two DataTables and returns another DataTable with the differences shown.

- Dynamic 'key' column (only single column, not multiple).
- Doesn't display rows that have the same data.
- Handles NULLs in data.
- Columns not in both tables.
- T=object comparisons.

**Populating the DataTables...**

```
    /// Build data and test the underlying method.
    public void Main()
    {
        Dictionary columns = new Dictionary();
        columns.Add("emp_num", typeof(int));
        columns.Add("salary", typeof(int));
        columns.Add("ov", typeof(double));

        DataTable left = new DataTable();
        foreach(KeyValuePair column in columns)
        {
            left.Columns.Add(column.Key, column.Value);
        }
        left.Rows.Add(455, 3000, 67.891);
        left.Rows.Add(677, 5000, 89.112);
        left.Rows.Add(778, 6000, 12.672);
        left.Rows.Add(9001, 5500, 12.672);
        left.Rows.Add(4, null, 9.2);
        //left.Dump("Left");

        DataTable right = new DataTable();
        right.Columns.Add("outlier", typeof(string));
        foreach (KeyValuePair column in columns)
        {
            right.Columns.Add(column.Key, column.Value);
        }
        right.Columns.Add("float", typeof(float));
        right.Rows.Add(0, 455, 3000, 67.891, 5);
        right.Rows.Add(1, 677, 5000, 50.113, 5);
        right.Rows.Add(2, 778, 5500, 12.672, 6);
        right.Rows.Add(2, 9000, 5500, 12.672, 6);
        right.Rows.Add(3, 4, 10, 9.2, 7);
        //right.Dump("Right");


        // Compare.
        DataTable results = Compare(left, right, "emp_num");
        //results.Dump("Results"); // Fancy table output via LINQPad.

        // Get the comparison columns for display.
        List comparedColumns = new List();
        foreach (DataColumn column in results.Columns)
        {
            comparedColumns.Add(column.ColumnName);
        }

        // Display the comparison rows.
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", comparedColumns));
        foreach(DataRow row in results.Rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", row.ItemArray));
        }
    }
```

[image: Fancy table output from LINQPad of the input.]

**Generic Method: DataTable Compare(DataTable, DataTable)**

```
    /// Compares the values of each row in the provided DataTables and returns any rows that have a difference based on a provided 'key' column.
    /// the 'pre' data.
    /// the 'post' data.
    /// Name of the column to use for matching rows.
    /// New DataTable populated with difference rows only.
    public DataTable Compare(DataTable left, DataTable right, string keyColumn)
    {
        const string Pre = "_Pre";
        const string Post = "_Post";

        DataColumn leftKey = left.Columns.Contains(keyColumn) ? left.Columns[keyColumn] : null;
        DataColumn rightKey = right.Columns.Contains(keyColumn) ? right.Columns[keyColumn] : null;

        if (leftKey == null || rightKey == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        // Get the matching columns between the two tables for doing comparisons.
        List comparisonColumns = new List();
        DataTable results = new DataTable();
        // Adding the key column to the front for sake of ease of viewing.
        results.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(leftKey.ColumnName, leftKey.DataType));
        foreach (DataColumn column in left.Columns)
        {
            if(column == leftKey)
            {
                continue;
            }

            // Remove any columns that are not present in the compare table.
            foreach (DataColumn compareColumn in right.Columns)
            {
                if (column.ColumnName == compareColumn.ColumnName && column.DataType == compareColumn.DataType)
                {
                    comparisonColumns.Add(column.ColumnName);
                    results.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(column.ColumnName + Pre, column.DataType));
                    results.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(column.ColumnName + Post, column.DataType));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (DataRow leftRow in left.Rows)
        {
            object key = leftRow.Field(leftKey);
            string filterExpression = string.Format("{0} = {1}", keyColumn, key);
            DataRow rightRow = right.Select(filterExpression).SingleOrDefault();
            // Need a row for a comparison to be valid.
            if (rightRow == null)
            {
                continue;
            }

            List comparison = new List();
            comparison.Add(key);
            bool isDiff = false;
            foreach (string comparisonColumn in comparisonColumns)
            {
                object pre = leftRow.ItemArray[left.Columns.IndexOf(comparisonColumn)];
                comparison.Add(pre);
                object post = rightRow.ItemArray[right.Columns.IndexOf(comparisonColumn)];
                comparison.Add(post);

                // Only need the row if the values differ in at least one column.
                isDiff |= (pre == null && post != null) || (pre != null && post == null) || (!pre.Equals(post));
            }
            if (isDiff)
            {
                results.Rows.Add(comparison.ToArray());
            }
        }

        return results;
    }
```

**Output:**

[image: Fancy table output from LINQPad of the output.]

```
    emp_num, salary_Pre, salary_Post, ov_Pre, ov_Post
    677, 5000, 5000, 89.112, 50.113
    778, 6000, 5500, 12.672, 12.672
    4, , 10, 9.2, 9.2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get all keys first, then create a new `Summary` objects, put the data there and let it do the comparison work. Finally you can do whatever you want with it:

```
void Main()
{
    var dt1 = new DataTable();
    dt1.Columns.Add("emp_num", typeof(int));
    dt1.Columns.Add("salary", typeof(int));
    dt1.Columns.Add("ov", typeof(double));
    dt1.Rows.Add(455, 3000, 67.891);
    dt1.Rows.Add(677, 5000, 89.112);
    dt1.Rows.Add(778, 6000, 12.672);

    var dt2 = new DataTable();
    dt2.Columns.Add("emp_num", typeof(int));
    dt2.Columns.Add("salary", typeof(int));
    dt2.Columns.Add("ov", typeof(double));
    dt2.Rows.Add(455, 3000, 67.891);
    dt2.Rows.Add(677, 5000, 50.113);
    dt2.Rows.Add(778, 5500, 12.672);
    dt2.Rows.Add(779, 5500, 12.672);

    var keys = new HashSet<int>(dt1.AsEnumerable().Select (x => (int)x["emp_num"]));
    keys.UnionWith(dt2.AsEnumerable().Select (x => (int)x["emp_num"]));

    keys.Dump("emp_num (keys)");

    var results = keys.Select (emp_num => 
    {
        var rowOff = dt1.Select("emp_num = " + emp_num).FirstOrDefault();
        var rowOn = dt2.Select("emp_num = " + emp_num).FirstOrDefault();
        return new Summary(emp_num, rowOff, rowOn);
    });

    results.Dump("Summary");
}
```

`Summary` helper class:

```
class Summary
{
    public Summary(int emp_num, DataRow rowOff, DataRow rowOn)
    {
        this.emp_num = emp_num;

        if (rowOff != null)
        {
            salary_off = (int)rowOff["salary"];
            ov_off = (double)rowOff["ov"];
        }

        if (rowOn != null)
        {
            salary_on = (int)rowOn["salary"];
            ov_on = (double)rowOn["ov"];
        }
    }
    public int emp_num;

    public int salary_off ;
    public int salary_on;
    public bool salarySame { get { return salary_off == salary_on; }  }

    public double ov_off ;
    public double ov_on;
    public bool ovSame { get { return ov_off == ov_on; } }

}
```

[image: Summary]

Comment: +1 for the answer ,thanks a lot but this method is limited ,i expect generic method to do the comparison .

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare What do you mean by generic method? There is nothing about it in you question ;-)

Comment: I appreciate your effort a lot :) , i mean in the constructor u use specific fields `(int)rowOff["salary"]` ,`(double)rowOff["ov"]` and with specific types .
I want to use this method with any two datatables with any structure .

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to achieve your task:

```
 var dt1 = new DataTable();
        dt1.Columns.Add("emp_num", typeof(int));
        dt1.Columns.Add("salary", typeof(int));
        dt1.Columns.Add("ov", typeof(double));
        dt1.Columns[0].Unique = true;

        dt1.Rows.Add(455, 3000, 67.891);
        dt1.Rows.Add(677, 6000, 50.113);
        dt1.Rows.Add(778, 5500, 12.650);
        dt1.Rows.Add(779, 5500, 12.672);

        var dt2 = new DataTable();
        dt2.Columns.Add("emp_num", typeof(int));
        dt2.Columns.Add("salary", typeof(int));
        dt2.Columns.Add("ov", typeof(double));
        dt2.Columns[0].Unique = true;

        dt2.Rows.Add(455, 3000, 67.891);
        dt2.Rows.Add(677, 5000, 50.113);
        dt2.Rows.Add(778, 5500, 12.672);
        dt2.Rows.Add(779, 5500, 12.672);

        var dtListValues1 = new List<List<string>>();



        for (int j = 0; j < dt2.Rows.Count; j++)
        {
            var list = new List<string>();
            for (var i = 0; i < dt2.Columns.Count; i++)
            {                

                    list.Add(dt2.Rows[j][i].ToString());
                list.Add("===");

                    list.Add(dt1.Rows[j][i].ToString());
                list.Add("||");
                if(dt2.Rows[j][i].ToString() == dt1.Rows[j][i].ToString())
                {
                    list.Add("true");
                }
                else
                {
                    list.Add("false");
                }

            }
            dtListValues1.Add(list);
        }

        var rowsWithDifferentCells = dtListValues1.Where(x => x.Contains("false"));


        foreach (var item in dtListValues1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Row-->> "+ string.Join(",",item));
        }
        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");
        foreach (var item in rowsWithDifferentCells)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Row with different cell-->> "+string.Join(",", item));
        }
```

I put all test data in a `List<List<string>>()`, in the process I also made check if the values are the same. Then I put a filter on false, to show me only the rows which contain cells with different values.

You just need to put this code in a ConsoleApp. and test it.

For sure is not the best approach,but is a quick way to check your data.

Answer (score 1):

If this is SQL related, then you could use the except SQL command:

SELECT * FROM TB_Online
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM TB_Offline

You can take a look [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2779/ways-to-compare-and-find-differences-for-sql-server-tables-and-data/), under "Compare Tables Using the EXCEPT Clause"

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take on it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;

namespace SO_DataTableCompare
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /// Build data and test the underlying method.
            Dictionary<string,Type> columns = new Dictionary<string, Type>();
            columns.Add("emp_num", typeof(int));
            columns.Add("salary", typeof(int));
            columns.Add("ov", typeof(double));

            DataTable left = new DataTable();
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string,Type> column in columns)
            {
                left.Columns.Add(column.Key, column.Value);
            }
            left.Rows.Add(455, 3000, 67.891);
            left.Rows.Add(677, 5000, 89.112);
            left.Rows.Add(778, 6000, 12.672);
            left.Rows.Add(9001, 5500, 12.672);
            left.Rows.Add(4, null, 9.2);
            //left.Dump("Left");

            DataTable right = new DataTable();
            right.Columns.Add("outlier", typeof(string));
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Type> column in columns)
            {
                right.Columns.Add(column.Key, column.Value);
            }
            right.Columns.Add("float", typeof(float));
            right.Rows.Add(0, 455, 3000, 67.891, 5);
            right.Rows.Add(1, 677, 5000, 50.113, 5);
            right.Rows.Add(2, 778, 5500, 12.672, 6);
            right.Rows.Add(2, 9000, 5500, 12.672, 6);
            right.Rows.Add(3, 4, 10, 9.2, 7);
            //right.Dump("Right");


            // Compare.
            DataTable results = Compare(left, right, "emp_num");
            //results.Dump("Results"); // Fancy table output via LINQPad.

            // Get the comparison columns for display.
            List<string> comparedColumns = new List<string>();
            foreach (DataColumn column in results.Columns)
            {
                comparedColumns.Add(column.ColumnName);
            }

            // Display the comparison rows.
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", comparedColumns));
            foreach (DataRow row in results.Rows)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", row.ItemArray));
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static DataTable Compare(DataTable left, DataTable right, string keyColumn, string suffix1="_off",string suffix2="_on")
        {
            var columns = left.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>().Select(c => c.ColumnName).ToList();
            var updated = left.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
                .Join(right.Rows.OfType<DataRow>(), row => row[keyColumn], row => row[keyColumn], (row1, row2) => new { key = row1[keyColumn], row1, row2 })
                .Where(o => o.row2!=null && !DataRowSame(o.row1, o.row2, columns));
            //var deleted = left.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Except(right.Rows.OfType<DataRow>(), new DataRowKeyComparer(keyColumn));
            //var inserted = right.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Except(left.Rows.OfType<DataRow>(), new DataRowKeyComparer(keyColumn));
            var result = new DataTable();
            result.Columns.Add(keyColumn, left.Columns[keyColumn].DataType);
            int k = 0;
            foreach (var name in columns.Where(c=>c!=keyColumn))
            {
                k++;
                result.Columns.Add(name + suffix1, left.Columns[name].DataType);
                result.Columns.Add(name + suffix2, right.Columns[name].DataType);
                result.Columns.Add("s"+k, typeof(int));
            }
            result.BeginLoadData();
            foreach (var upd in updated)
            {
                var vals = new[] { upd.key }.Concat(
                        columns.Where(c => c != keyColumn)
                            .Select(c => new
                            {
                                l = upd.row1[c],
                                r = upd.row2[c]
                            })
                            .SelectMany(o => new object[] { o.l, o.r, object.Equals(o.l, o.r) ? 1 : 0 })
                    ).ToArray();
                result.LoadDataRow(vals, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);
            }
            result.EndLoadData();
            return result;
        }

        private static bool DataRowSame(DataRow row1, DataRow row2, List<string> columns)
        {
            foreach (var name in columns)
            {
                if (!object.Equals(row1[name], row2[name])) return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    internal class DataRowKeyComparer : IEqualityComparer<DataRow>
    {
        private string keyColumn;

        public DataRowKeyComparer(string keyColumn)
        {
            this.keyColumn = keyColumn;
        }

        public bool Equals(DataRow x, DataRow y)
        {
            return object.Equals(x[keyColumn], y[keyColumn]);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(DataRow obj)
        {
            return obj.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution : Absolute Basic
You can create Table structure Dynamically as well.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //Table 1
            DataTable table1 = new DataTable();

            table1.Columns.Add("emp_num(key)", typeof(Int32));
            table1.Columns.Add("salary", typeof(float));
            table1.Columns.Add("ov", typeof(float));

            table1.Rows.Add(455, 3000, 67.56);
            table1.Rows.Add(456, 4000, 77.56);
            table1.Rows.Add(457, 6000, 87.56);

            grdTable1.DataSource = table1;
            grdTable1.DataBind();


            //Table 2
            DataTable table2 = new DataTable();
            table2.Columns.Add("emp_num(key)", typeof(Int32));
            table2.Columns.Add("salary", typeof(float));
            table2.Columns.Add("ov", typeof(float));

            table2.Rows.Add(455, 3000, 67.56);
            table2.Rows.Add(456, 4000, 27.56);
            table2.Rows.Add(457, 5000, 87.56);

            grdTable2.DataSource = table2;
            grdTable2.DataBind();

            //Compare
            DataTable result = new DataTable();
            result.Columns.Add("emp_num(key)", typeof(Int32));
            result.Columns.Add("salary_Table1", typeof(float));
            result.Columns.Add("salary_Table2", typeof(float));
            result.Columns.Add("same_Salary", typeof(string));
            result.Columns.Add("ov_Table1", typeof(float));
            result.Columns.Add("ov_Table2", typeof(float));
            result.Columns.Add("Same_OV", typeof(string));
            foreach (DataRow t1r in table1.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataRow t2r in table2.Rows)
                {
                    var array1 = t1r.ItemArray;
                    var array2 = t2r.ItemArray;
                    //Check ID Column to decide if compare needs to be done 
                    if (array1[0].ToString() == array2[0].ToString())
                    {
                        if (array1.SequenceEqual(array2))
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            int SalSame = 0;
                            int OvSame = 0;
                            if (array1[1].ToString() == array2[1].ToString())
                            {
                                SalSame = 1;
                            }
                            if (array1[2].ToString() == array2[2].ToString())
                            {
                                OvSame = 1;
                            }

                            result.Rows.Add(array1[0].ToString(), array1[1].ToString(), array2[1].ToString(), SalSame, array1[2].ToString(), array2[2].ToString(), OvSame);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            grdresult.DataSource = result;
            grdresult.DataBind();
        }
    }
}



<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>

            <h3>First Table </h3>
            <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdTable1"></asp:GridView>
            <h3>Second Table </h3>
            <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdTable2"></asp:GridView>

            <h3>Result Table </h3>
            <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdresult"></asp:GridView>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

[Result ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taPIJ.png)

```html
 <div>
    
        <h3>First Table </h3>
        <div>
 <table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="grdTable1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tr>
   <th scope="col">emp_num(key)</th><th scope="col">salary</th><th scope="col">ov</th>
  </tr><tr>
   <td>455</td><td>3000</td><td>67.56</td>
  </tr><tr>
   <td>456</td><td>4000</td><td>77.56</td>
  </tr><tr>
   <td>457</td><td>6000</td><td>87.56</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
        <h3>Second Table </h3>
         <div>
 <table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="grdTable2" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tr>
   <th scope="col">emp_num(key)</th><th scope="col">salary</th><th scope="col">ov</th>
  </tr><tr>
   <td>455</td><td>3000</td><td>67.56</td>
  </tr><tr>
   <td>456</td><td>4000</td><td>27.56</td>
  </tr><tr>
   <td>457</td><td>5000</td><td>87.56</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>

        <h3>Result Table </h3>
         <div>
 <table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="grdresult" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tr>
   <th scope="col">emp_num(key)</th><th scope="col">salary_Table1</th><th scope="col">salary_Table2</th><th scope="col">same_Salary</th><th scope="col">ov_Table1</th><th scope="col">ov_Table2</th><th scope="col">Same_OV</th>
  </tr><tr>
   <td>456</td><td>4000</td><td>4000</td><td>1</td><td>77.56</td><td>27.56</td><td>0</td>
  </tr><tr>
   <td>457</td><td>6000</td><td>5000</td><td>0</td><td>87.56</td><td>87.56</td><td>1</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

In SQL query, you can JOIN two tables and using SELECT-CASE statement to determine the difference value for each column:
e.g

```
SELECT 
TB_Online.emp_num,
TB_Online.salary_on,
TB_Offline.salary_off,
SELECT CASE TB_Online.salary_on = Tb_offline.salary_off then 0 ELSE 1 END AS salary_same
...
FROM TB_Online INNER JOIN TB_Offline
ON TB_Online.emp_num = TB_Offline.emp_num
```

To remove all rows have exact values, you can SELECT again base on above result table

Comment: sorry , your answer relating to the `sql` not the `.net`